Compare elements and their position in two python lists
I have two lists: list_1 and list_2.
list_1 contains integers,
list_2 contains integers + chars (I added it in list_2 by concatenating int, str using the str() func).
list_1 = ['101', '102', and so on..]
list_2 = ['www.example.com/101', 'www.example.com/102' and so on]

Now I want to compare the integer elements inside these two lists with each other one by one to verify if all elements are in same positions in both lists. list_2 also contains url, but I want to skip that while comparing.
list_1[0] == list_2[0]
list_1[1] == list_2[1] and so on... 

The lists are huge so I need loop but it is not iterating integer.
data1 = 101
data2 = 200
url = "www.example.com/"

hrc_list = []
fp_list = []


#Generate integer range and put it inside list
for hrc in range(data1, data2 + 1):
    hrc_list.append(hrc)
#Concat URL + Integer and save inside the FP_LIST
    fp_list.append(url + str(hrc))


# LIST ELEMENTS ORDER COMPARISON AND VALIDATION

for items in hrc_list:
    if range(hrc_list) == range(fp_list):
        print("Equal")
    else:
        print("Not Equal")

The output shows: List object cannot be interpreted by Integer.
I tried to use for loop with range function to compare two lists and print if its equal or not. But I don't have an idea how to compare the position and element of both lists with each other without comparing url. I want to validate the contents and positions of both lists.
You can see above I only want to compare integers from both lists with along their positions. I dont think sort() or related functions can work in this case.

You might want to look into enumerate.  Or even better, zip.

You get this error because you use range(hrc_list) where hrc_list is a list, but range expects to receive a number, not a list.

I would go about this like this:
equal = True
for i in range(hrc_list):
    if hrc_list[i] != int(fp_list[i[len(url):]]):
        equal = False
        break

This first assumes that they are equal. Then, it iterates through both lists. It takes the value in hrc_list and then the value from fp_list but slices the string to only include the integer part. It then converts it to an integer so that it can be compared with the value at hrc_list. If the comparison is not True, then it just continues iterating through the list until it has finished. However, if at any point it is True, it changes qual to be False and then breaks as it is no longer necessary to check the rest of the lists.
I hope this helps.

hrc_list is a list object, so range(hrc_list) will raise a TypeError. Since you use hrc_list[i], I assume you meant range(len(hrc_list)), but that construct is considered unpythonic and inferior to enumerate(hrc_list). Last, but not least, i is an int, so what is i[len(url):] supposed to mean?

As suggested by Scott, you might want to use zip:
equal = True
for a, b in zip(hrc_list, fp_list):
    equal = equal and (str(a) == b[len(url):])
    if not equal:
        break  # Don't do extra work

if equal:
    print("Equal")
else:
    print("Not Equal")

